Why does the spacex booster look like it's all on fire?
FLIGHT IFT-5:

No way is that ullage rockets. It looks like the fuel tank cracked and all the fuel splashed out and caught fire. I'm surprised the whole thing didn't explode.

Which flight is this?

Flight IFT-5. The only flight where the booster returned to the launch tower.

the remit of this website is to produce Q+As that are also useful to future readers. Please take some extra time when writing your questions to add detail so a future reader wondering the same thing can find the question and its answer.

That appears to be not a leak, but an intentional off-gassing of methane from a side-vent. I don't know if this was a planned burn-off or an emergency overpressure valve that opened to prevent tank damage, but it doesn't seem to be a broken tank or anything of that nature.
Here's a better view of it just at landing:

Looking at the stream of the landing process, it looks to me like there was some gas coming out from that port the whole time. It gets ignited when the engines kick on for the final landing burn, then gets much larger as the middle-ring engines shut down (leaving only the three they use for the final approach).
Presumably, heated by reentry and then flying through its own exhaust stream, the fuel in the booster's tanks is rapidly boiling off, and the excess gas is being dumped overboard instead of fed into the engines. When it's burning 15 engines for deceleration, there's not much excess gas, but then they cut out 12 of them, and that means there's a lot more excess that can't stay in the tank, so the plume gets much larger at that point.
The methane caught fire from the heat of the rockets below, but it's only burning in atmospheric oxygen, so it can't enter and travel up into the ship because there's no oxygen inside the lines to burn with. It's possible there's also an oxygen dump happening somewhere else that isn't as visible because it isn't actively on fire. (If it were me, I'd put the oxygen vent near the top of the booster and on the opposite side from the methane vent, so as to keep the two as far apart as possible -- maybe somewhere around where the gantry arms are in the photo -- but I'm not aware of any actual plumbing information regarding this.)

My naive assumption was it being used as sideways stabilizing maneuver

Nah, it's clear from looking at the flame that it's not producing thrust. That's just something burning and flowing upward.

Agreed - anything that produces thrust produces much faster-moving and much brighter flames than that. Compare it with the engines that are firing in that image.
